# How do i sort keys in reverse order in java List<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist

I get keys in ascending order when I am executing this code

```
List<Integer> sortedKey = groupedData.keySet().stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How do I get them in descending order?

Comment: What is `groupedData`?

Comment: Comparator.reverseOrder is probably what you need. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder()) as an argument to the `.sorted()` method to specify the comparison to be used while sorting the stream.

As the name suggests, [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder())
is a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) that returns `Integer` results in  descending order.

```
List<Integer> sortedKey = groupedData.keySet().stream()
.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

## `Comparator.reverseOrder`

The following might work, though I’ve not tested. Pass a `Comparator` to the `Stream#sorted` method. The comparator returned by a call to [`Comparator.reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder()) imposes the reverse of the natural ordering.

```
List<Integer> sortedKey = 
    groupedData
    .keySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted( Comparator.reverseOrder() )
    .toList()  
;
```

Before Java 16, make that last call `.collect( Collectors.toList()`. )